SSRS Rest API Error "The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services."
I am using powershell to upload a RDL file to a specific folder in a SSRS instance (SQL Server 2019 Reporting Services Version 15.0.8863.19101)
    $sourceItemPath = 'C:\Temp\ReportFolder\Report.rdl'
    $reportName = 'Report'
    $apiPath = 'http://localhost/reports/api/v2.0'
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($SSRSReportUser, $SecurePassword)
    $targetPath = "/Reports"
    $sourceFileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($sourceItemPath)
    $sourceFileContent2 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String( $sourceFileContent )

    # ------------------
    # Create Report
    # ------------------

    $CreateReportJSON=
    '
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Model.Report",
        "Content": "YYY",
        "ContentType": "application/rdl",
        "Name":  "XXX",
        "Path":  "/ZZZ/XXX"
    }
    '
    $targetPath = $targetPath.Replace('/','')
    $CreateReportJSON = $CreateReportJSON.Replace('XXX',$reportName)
    $CreateReportJSON = $CreateReportJSON.Replace('YYY',$sourceFileContent2)
    $CreateReportJSON = $CreateReportJSON.Replace('ZZZ',$targetPath)
    $CreateReportURI = "$apiPath/Reports(Path='/$targetPath')"
    $createReportResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $CreateReportURI -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $CreateReportJSON -Credential $creds

When I attempt to upload the report, I get the following error.
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error":{
    "code":"1027","message":"The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed 
or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1206, position 80."
  }
}

The beginning of the file is...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:am="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/authoringmetadata">

I can upload the file via the SSRS UI!  Why can't I upload it via Powershell?  Can I get rid of the schema validation?
ADDING RSPortal Log File (2024-07-10 15:34 EDT)...
2024-07-10 15:14:40.4731|INFO|26|Received request POST /api/v2.0/Reports| RequestID = s_f7b1ad7e-cae6-42dc-a0c4-e89f532b2e5c 
2024-07-10 15:14:40.6673|ERROR|26|OData exception occurred: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1206, position 80.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, ItemType ItemType, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.ReportingService2010.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.<>c__DisplayClass120_0.<CreateCatalogItem>b__0()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.CreateCatalogItem(String itemType, String name, String parent, Boolean overwrite, Byte[] definition, Property[] properties, Warning[]& warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapRS2010Proxy.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateCatalogItem>b__0()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapAuthenticationHelper.ExecuteWithWindowsAuth[TReturn](SoapHttpClientProtocol soapClient, IPrincipal userPrincipal, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemRepository.CreateReport(RSService rsService, IPrincipal userPrincipal, String reportName, String parentFolder, Boolean overwrite, Byte[] definition, Property[] properties)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemRepository.CreateItem(IPrincipal userPrincipal, CatalogItem catalogItem, CatalogItem& createdItem)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemRepository.Create[T](IPrincipal userPrincipal, T catalogItem, T& createdItem)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.ODataWebApi.Controllers.Reflection.EntitySetReflectionODataController`1.Post(ODataPath oDataPath, T value)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext().| RequestID = s_f7b1ad7e-cae6-42dc-a0c4-e89f532b2e5c 
2024-07-10 15:14:40.6673|INFO|26|Sending response. Response code  500, Elapsed time 0:00:00.1955089| RequestID = s_f7b1ad7e-cae6-42dc-a0c4-e89f532b2e5c 


Try using the Fiddler proxy to capture the API calls from the SSRS UI and see where the differences are.

Fiddler does not capture requests from powershell, on from the SSRS UI

Try the Postman proxy then.
